# Prove: $n\log(n^2) + (\log\ n)^2 = O(n\log(n))$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Prove: $n\log(n^2) + (\log n)^2 = O(n\log(n))$

I'm trying to use the Big Oh definition, what I reached so far is:

$f(n)$ is in $O(g(n))$ if there is $M > 0,∈\mathbb{R}$ such that whenever $m > x$ we have $|f(m)|<M|(m)|$

How do I, however, continue from here?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Use that $\log n < n$ and $\log (n^2)=2\log n$.

Comment: I think one should use $\log n < n^{0.5}$ or something like that instead of $\log n < n$, because $\log n < n$ yields $(\log n)^2 < n^2$.

Comment: @Sanya $(\log n)^2<n \log n$

Answer (score 3):

You could also apply the limit definition

\begin{align}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\log(n^2) + (\log n)^2}{n\log n}&=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n\log n}{n\log n}+\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\log n)^2}{n\log n}\\&=
\limsup_{n\to\infty} 2+\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n}\\&<\infty
\end{align}

therefore $n\log(n^2) + (\log n)^2=O(n\log n)$.

Answer (score 2):

We will take $M = 4$ and $x = e$. Then, for $n > x$,
$$
\begin{align*}
n \log (n^2) + (\log n)^2 &= 2n \log n + (\log n)^2 & (\because \text{Property of log})\\
&\le 2n \log n + (\sqrt{n})^2 = 2n \log n + n & (\because \log n \le \sqrt n \ \ \text{for all} \ \ n \ge 0) \\
&\le 3n \log n & (\because \log n > 1 \ \ \text{for all} \ \ n > e) \\
& < 4n \log n = M (n \log n) &
\end{align*}
$$
So, by definition of big-Oh notation, we are done.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$n\ \log(n^2) + (\log\ n)^2 =2n\log n+\log n \cdot \log n$$

and

$$\frac{n\ \log(n^2) + (\log\ n)^2 }{n\log n}=\frac{2n\log n+\log n \cdot \log n}{n\log n}=2+\frac{\log n}n \to 2$$

therefore

$$n\ \log(n^2) + (\log\ n)^2 =O(n\log n)$$

Answer (score 2):

$n\log(n^2)=2nlog n$ is $O(n\log n)$ by definition and $\log^2n=o(n\log n)$ since 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log^2n}{n\log n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log n}{n }=0$$
and  *a fortiori*, $ \log^2n=O(n\log n)$, so that 
$$n\log(n^2)+\log^2n=O(n\log n)+O(n\log n)=O(n\log n).$$

Answer (score 0):

According to the formal definition of big-O, we have to show:
$$\exists c,{n_0} > 0,\;\;\forall n \ge {n_0} \to n\log {n^2} + {\log ^2}n \le c.n\log n
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaey4aIqIaam
% 4yaiaacYcacaWGUbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaicdaaeqaaOGaeyOpa4JaaGim
% aiaacYcacaaMe8UaaGjbVlabgcGiIiaad6gacqGHLjYScaWGUbWaaS
% baaSqaaiaaicdaaeqaaOGaeyOKH4QaamOBaiGacYgacaGGVbGaai4z
% aiaad6gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccqGHRaWkciGGSbGaai4Bai
% aacEgadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccaWGUbGaeyizImQaam4yaiaa
% c6cacaWGUbGaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaamOBaaaa!5A5E!
$$
Lets start:
$$\begin{array}{l}n\log {n^2} + {\log ^2}n \le c.n\log n \to 2n\log n + {\log ^2}n \le c.n\log n\\if\;n > 1 \to \log n > 0\\ \div \log n \to \frac{{2n\log n}}{{\log n}} + \frac{{{{\log }^2}n}}{{\log n}} \le \frac{{c.n\log n}}{{\log n}} \to 2n + \log n \le c.n\quad ;\;n > 1\;\\Let\;c = 3 \to \log n \le n\quad ;\;n > 1\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqababaaaaaaa
% aapeqaa8aacaWGUbGaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaamOBamaaCaaaleqa
% baGaaGOmaaaakiabgUcaRiGacYgacaGGVbGaai4zamaaCaaaleqaba
% GaaGOmaaaakiaad6gacqGHKjYOcaWGJbGaaiOlaiaad6gaciGGSbGa
% ai4BaiaacEgacaWGUbGaeyOKH4QaaGOmaiaad6gaciGGSbGaai4Bai
% aacEgacaWGUbGaey4kaSIaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbWaaWbaaSqabeaa
% caaIYaaaaOGaamOBaiabgsMiJkaadogacaGGUaGaamOBaiGacYgaca
% GGVbGaai4zaiaad6gaaeaacaWGPbGaamOzaiaaysW7caWGUbGaeyOp
% a4JaaGymaiabgkziUkGacYgacaGGVbGaai4zaiaad6gacqGH+aGpca
% aIWaaabaGaey49aGRaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaamOBaiabgkziUoaa
% laaabaGaaGOmaiaad6gaciGGSbGaai4BaiaacEgacaWGUbaabaGaci
% iBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaamOBaaaacqGHRaWkdaWcaaqaaiGacYgacaGG
% VbGaai4zamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaakiaad6gaaeaaciGGSbGaai
% 4BaiaacEgacaWGUbaaaiabgsMiJoaalaaabaGaam4yaiaac6cacaWG
% UbGaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaamOBaaqaaiGacYgacaGGVbGaai4zai
% aad6gaaaGaeyOKH4QaaGOmaiaad6gacqGHRaWkciGGSbGaai4Baiaa
% cEgacaWGUbGaeyizImQaam4yaiaac6cacaWGUbGaaGzbVlaacUdaca
% aMe8UaamOBaiabg6da+iaaigdacaaMe8oabaGaamitaiaadwgacaWG
% 0bGaaGjbVlaadogacqGH9aqpcaaIZaGaeyOKH4QaciiBaiaac+gaca
% GGNbGaamOBaiabgsMiJkaad6gacaaMf8Uaai4oaiaaysW7caWGUbGa
% eyOpa4JaaGymaaaaaa!BCD2!
$$
On the other hand, according to the function diagrams, we know:
$$\log n < n\;\;;\;for\;any\;n > 0 \to \log n < n\;\;;\;n > 1 \to we\;choose\;{n_0} = 2\;optionally.
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaciiBaiaac+
% gacaGGNbGaamOBaiabgYda8iaad6gacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaacUdacaaM
% e8UaamOzaiaad+gacaWGYbGaaGjbVlaadggacaWGUbGaamyEaiaays
% W7caWGUbGaeyOpa4JaaGimaiabgkziUkGacYgacaGGVbGaai4zaiaa
% d6gacqGH8aapcaWGUbGaaGjbVlaaysW7caGG7aGaaGjbVlaad6gacq
% GH+aGpcaaIXaGaeyOKH4Qaam4DaiaadwgacaaMe8Uaam4yaiaadIga
% caWGVbGaam4BaiaadohacaWGLbGaaGjbVlaad6gadaWgaaWcbaGaaG
% imaaqabaGccqGH9aqpcaaIYaGaaGjbVlaad+gaqaaaaaaaaaWdbiaa
% dchacaWG0bGaamyAaiaad+gacaWGUbGaamyyaiaadYgacaWGSbGaam
% yEaiaac6caaaa!784F!
$$
So, we proved:
$$c = 3,\;\;{n_0} = 2 \to \exists c,{n_0} > 0,\;\;\forall n \ge {n_0} \to n\log {n^2} + {\log ^2}n \le c.n\log n
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam4yaiabg2
% da9iaaiodacaGGSaGaaGjbVlaaysW7caWGUbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaicda
% aeqaaOGaeyypa0JaaGOmaiabgkziUkabgoGiKiaadogacaGGSaGaam
% OBamaaBaaaleaacaaIWaaabeaakiabg6da+iaaicdacaGGSaGaaGjb
% VlaaysW7cqGHaiIicaWGUbGaeyyzImRaamOBamaaBaaaleaacaaIWa
% aabeaakiabgkziUkaad6gaciGGSbGaai4BaiaacEgacaWGUbWaaWba
% aSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaey4kaSIaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbWaaWbaaS
% qabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaamOBaiabgsMiJkaadogacaGGUaGaamOBaiGa
% cYgacaGGVbGaai4zaiaad6gaaaa!6665!
$$